# How to integrate Chartboost rewarded video with MoPub mediation for iOS

Tags: ios, ads, mopub, chartboost

I make the game using Cocos2d-x ver. 3.4. I make the rewarded video with MoPub mediation in this game. I followed this [guide](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/wiki/Rewarded-Video-Integration) on official github wiki.
So, first I incorporated the MoPub iOS SDK and Chartboost SDK in the project.
 I set in `AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MoPub.h"
#import "MPRewardedVideo.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, MPRewardedVideoDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger coinAmount;

@end
```

in `AppDelegate.mm`:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    …
    [self loadRewardedVideo];

    return YES;
}

- (void)loadRewardedVideo {
    [[MoPub sharedInstance] initializeRewardedVideoWithGlobalMediationSettings:nil delegate:self];

    [MPRewardedVideo loadRewardedVideoAdWithAdUnitID:@“[MyAdUnitID]“ withMediationSettings:nil];
}

#pragma mark - MPRewardedVideoDelegate

- (void)rewardedVideoAdShouldRewardForAdUnitID:(NSString *)adUnitID reward:(MPRewardedVideoReward *)reward {
    if ([reward.currencyType isEqualToString:@"coin"]) {
        if ([reward.amount integerValue] == kMPRewardedVideoRewardCurrencyAmountUnspecified)
        {
            singleton->addToTotalCoins(10); // for test
        } else
        {
            singleton->addToTotalCoins([reward.amount integerValue]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is buttons "showRewardedVideo" handler in `RootViewController.mm`:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void) showRewardedVideo
{
    if ([MPRewardedVideo hasAdAvailableForAdUnitID:@"MyAdUnitID"])
    {
        [MPRewardedVideo presentRewardedVideoAdForAdUnitID:@"MyAdUnitID" fromViewController:self];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Something went wrong"
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

I set in `MoPubSDK`->`AdNetworkSupport`->`Chartboost`->`ChartboostRewardedVideoCustomEvent.m`:

```
- (void)requestRewardedVideoWithCustomEventInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *appId = [info objectForKey:@"MyChartboostAppID"];

    NSString *appSignature = [info objectForKey:@"MyChartboostAppSignature"];
…
}
```

But when I run the application, I get in
 `- (void)communicatorDidReceiveAdConfiguration:(MPAdConfiguration *)configuration`
the `_networkType` propertie = `@"clear"`
and get a message

> MOPUB: Rewarded video ad is fetching ad network type: clear

The video is not displayed, and I get my alert window from `RootViewController.mm`  `-(void)showRewardedVideo` method.

Seems MoPub doesn't know about Chartboost. I think, I need define settings in `initializeRewardedVideoWithGlobalMediationSettings:nil`, but how I should make this? I didn't found info about this.
Please tell me, what else needs to be done. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work??

Comment: No, I proposed the customer avoid the MoPub mediation and use only Chartboost. Chartboost himself works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is using no argument: `initializeRewardedVideoWithGlobalMediationSettings:nil` in `loadRewardedVideo` in `AppDelegate.mm`

[In your guide](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/wiki/Rewarded-Video-Integration#advanced-mediation-settings) they state that

> Mediation settings enable you to pass in third-party network specific settings and can be provided as additional parameters during the rewarded video initialization call

so most probably you need that argument to be non-nil. Also, `withMediationSettings` should be non-null if you don't want MoPub to choose network by itself. They say it [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/blob/master/MoPubSDK/RewardedVideo/MPRewardedVideo.h):

> The mediation settings array should contain ad network specific objects for networks that may be loaded for the given ad unit ID

Comment: Thank you for response. I read this. But I don't know how to specify this settings? What exactly should they contain? I can't found info about this in my Chartboost SDK classes or in the Internet. For example, for [Fyber mediation](http://developer.fyber.com/content/current/ios/rewarded-video/adding-networks/chartboost/) you should to add Chartboost settings into info.plist. But there is no information for MoPub.

Comment: I can't find what they mean either. I would experiment in your place. for `initializeRewardedVideoWithGlobalMediationSettings` they say argument is NSArray of _configurations for all rewarded video ad networks_ so, I don't know, feed this argument in there `@[@"ChartboostInterstitialCustomEvent"]`, worst case it will give you an exception saying what kind of objects you should give to it. Then do same for `withMediationSettings`.

Comment: Something does not work. I send settings to `+(void)loadRewardedVideoAdWithAdUnitID` in `MPRewardedVideo.m`, but I get still in `-(void)communicatorDidReceiveAdConfiguration:(MPAdConfiguration *)configuration` the '_networkType' propertie = '@"clear"' and no rewarded video. And no errors. Thank you for response, I'll try something else.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you contact Mopub/Twitter support, any news from their side?